# Is it better to answer kaddish or use that time to catch up?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, kaddish

You've fallen behind because you can't keep up with congregation's prayer speed and the chazzan begins to say kaddish. Which option is preferable?

**A**. Pause your own prayer, answer kaddish completely, and fall further behind.

**B**. Don't answer Amen and continue your own prayer in the hopes of catching up to the congregation by the end of the kaddish.

**C**. Continue your own prayer and simultaneously answer Amen to the kaddish in between words of your own prayer.

Comment: And Which prayer?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to narrow down the question to one possible scenario.

Comment: My intention was that the law may differ per prayer.